# Extracting last element of nested array with recursion

Tags: javascript

I want to flat an array, recursion function calls itself till the last  element array but not the last element string, I feel like I am missing something important in understanding how recursion works, the string itself is not added to an empty array.

```js
const nested = [[[[[['string']]]]], 5, '7'];

const funcTest = function (arr) {
  const final = [];
  arr.forEach(el => {
    if (Array.isArray(el)) {
      console.log(el);
      funcTest(el);
    } else final.push(el);
  });
  return final;
};  

console.log(funcTest(nested));
```

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: I want this  ['string', 5, '7']

Comment: Did you try `.flat`?  Consider `[[[[[['string']]]]], 5, '7'].flat(Infinity)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the result of the recursive calls.

```js
const
    nested = [[[[[['string']]]]], 5, '7'];

const funcTest = function (arr) {
  const final = [];
  arr.forEach(el => {
    if (Array.isArray(el)) {
      console.log(el);
      final.push(...funcTest(el)); // <-
    } else final.push(el);
  });
  return final;
};  

console.log(funcTest(nested));
```

Another recursive approach:

```js
const
    nested = [[[[[['string']]]]], 5, '7'];
    flatValues = item => Array.isArray(item)
        ? item.flatMap(flatValues)
        : item;

console.log(flatValues(nested));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can Flattening all nested arrays With [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) taking argument `depth` of `Infinity`:

```js
    const nested = [[[[[["string"]]]]], 5, "7"];
    nested.flat(Infinity); //['string', 5, '7']
```

***depth:*** The depth level specifying how deep a nested array structure should be flattened. Defaults to 1.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: if that is really an answer to the recursive problem, the question would be a duplicate.

Comment: It's not the answer, but just I would share a trick to flattening an array without using recursion or for-loops!

Comment: Thank you  very much

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you don't use the return value of the recursive `funcTest` call.

What you want to do:

```js
const superFlat = (arr) => {
  const result = [];
  
  arr.forEach((item) => {
    if (!Array.isArray(item)) result.push(item);
    else result.push(...superFlat(item));
  });

  return result;
}
```

Or just use `arr.flat(Infinity)`

Comment: Thank you  very much